# Fetching Data from XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Currently am trying to fetch data from an XML to my SelectBox. 
My XML Output is like ;

```
<1>
    <book_able>0</book_able>
    <CODE>AF</CODE>
    <NAME>Afghanistan</NAME>
</1>
<2>
    <book_able>1</book_able>
    <CODE>AL</CODE>
    <NAME>Albanie</NAME>
</2>
<3>
    <book_able>1</book_able>
    <CODE>DZ</CODE>
    <NAME>Algerie</NAME>
</3>
<6>
    <book_able>1</book_able>
    <CODE>AS</CODE>
    <NAME>Samoa Americaines</NAME>
</6>
<8>
    <book_able>1</book_able>
    <CODE>AD</CODE>
    <NAME>Andorre</NAME>
</8>
<9>
    <book_able>1</book_able>
    <CODE>AO</CODE>
    <NAME>Angola</NAME>
</9>
<11>
    <book_able>1</book_able>
    <CODE>AI</CODE>
    <NAME>Anguilla</NAME>
</11>
```

Here the numbers denoted the order of the countries. But that numbers are not correctly ordered. 
For Example: After <3> the next number is <6>.
So its hard to fetching using a loop.
is there any method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method to process XML documents.

Your XML is not valid. You can't have elements like <11>

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

**XML Naming Rules**
XML elements must follow these naming rules:

Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
**Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character**
Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
Names cannot contain spaces
Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

Comment: Because jQuery's parseXML uses the browser's native XML parsing will it handle invalid XML like this question? I know later versions of jQuery took a hardline in dealing with invalid JSON (requiring keys to be quoted) I guess I could just try but I'm on an iPhone at the moment.

Comment: Yes it is. Quote from jQuery Documentation: jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to create a valid XML Document.

Comment: If we request data as JSON can we handle this problem? How I can handle this situation when its as in JSON format ?